# Time triggered function in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help with time trigger based function execution.

I have got a google sheet with a macro recorded which applies a filter to one column in a sheet. I would like to invoke this macro every 5 minutes.

I tried to do this via appscript and created a trigger attached to the function created by the macro. The time trigger is properly executed however no filter is applied.

Comment: Try writing the macro without using the phrase `active` in anything.  You may find that it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

A five minute trigger:

for function named functionName.

```
function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "functionName").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionName').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
}
```